Custom SingleValue Button Not Clickable
I am trying to add an edit button (which currently triggers an alert) to my react-select component. However, this makes the newly added button unclickable; instead, it opens the react-select menu. Stopping propagation does not solve the issue.
const CustomOption = (props) => {
  const handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("This is working like I want");
  };

  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <div className="test">
        <span>{props.children}</span>
        <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const option = [
    { value: "Spring", label: "Spring" },
    { value: "Summer", label: "Summer" },
    { value: "Autumn", label: "Autumn" },
    { value: "Winter", label: "Winter" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        options={option}
        components={{ SingleValue: CustomSingleValue }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Question: Why doesn't the button inside CustomSingleValue work (while the one inside CustomOption does), and how can I fix it?
Code SandBox
This is especially frustrating because CustomOption, which uses the exact same code, works fine.
Working vs not working
Full code including working CustomOption:
// This isn't working like I want
const CustomSingleValue = (props) => {
  const handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("This I can't click");
  };

  return (
    <components.SingleValue {...props}>
      <div className="test">
        <span>{props.children}</span>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </components.SingleValue>
  );
};

// This is working how I want
const CustomOption = (props) => {
  const handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("This is working like I want");
  };

  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <div className="test">
        <span>{props.children}</span>
        <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
      </div>
    </components.Option>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const option = [
    { value: "Spring", label: "Spring" },
    { value: "Summer", label: "Summer" },
    { value: "Autumn", label: "Autumn" },
    { value: "Winter", label: "Winter" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        className="dropdown"
        options={option}
        placeholder="Click on a option and then try to click the edit button"
        components={{ SingleValue: CustomSingleValue, Option: CustomOption }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


Issue number one: you have a react-select input overlayed your component, hence you click it instead of your single value component:

To address that, you need to add z-index:
const singleValueStyles = {
  singleValue: (styles) => ({ ...styles, "z-index": 2 }),
};
...

<Select
  className="dropdown"
  options={option}
  styles={singleValueStyles} // 
...


After that, the button works well, however, we still get the dropdown opened. That's because react-select uses onMouseDown rather that onClick. The easiest way to fix it is to use onMouseDown too:
<button onMouseDown={handleEdit}>Edit</button>

If you want to keep onClick, just add another handler for onMouseDown that only stops propagation.

Thanks! It really did not occur to me that it was a css/styling issue rather then me just javascript one.

you see when an option is selected and is being shown in the input, it is a layer underneath the input, thus, despite the fact that you are seeing the option there, when you click on it, you are not actually clicking on that, you are clicking on the select input causing the options dropdown to open.

enter image description here
just add position: relative on the option container, it will work

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
